# Big-O cost of pyramid algorithm

Tags: javascript, big-o

I'm working through trying to understand big-O notation, and I was wondering: what would be the big-O cost of a pyramid algorithm?

`pyramid(2)` results in:

```
 # 
###
```

I know one way of solving it is using nested `for`-loops like:

```
function pyramid(n) {
    const totalLengthOfRow = n * 2 - 1
    for (let row = 0; row < n; row++) {
        var line = ''
        var middleCol = Math.floor(totalLengthOfRow / 2)
        
        for (let col = 0; col < totalLengthOfRow; col++) {
            if (col >= middleCol - row && col <= middleCol + row) {
                line += '#'
            } else {
                line += ' '
            }
        }
        console.log(line)
    }
}
```

So that should be `O(n2)` right? Since both `for`-loops grow as `n` grows. But what if I use `string.repeat` and get rid of the inner `for` loop?

Something like:

```
const numberOfHashes = 1 + row * 2
const numberOfSpaces = n * 2 - 1 - numberOfHashes    
var line = ' '.repeat(numberOfSpaces / 2) + '#'.repeat(numberOfHashes) + ' '.repeat(numberOfSpaces / 2)
```

Is `repeat` just like a `for`-loop, since it also repeats based on the size of `n`?

Answer (score 2):

Let's say the second algorithm is a bit smarter, because at each step you don't need to check (with the conditional statement) which character you have to print.

Nevertheless, the JS `repeat` function is no more than [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) for a loop. Thus, the two algorithms are (not only semantically, but also asymptotically) equivalent and, in particular, both are `O(n^2)`.